# Phonegap, Running a script only once from initial install

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have some javascript to read in database file to then load into Phonegap's own database. At the moment it triggers through onDeviceReady() so of course it gets processed every time I load into the page or return to it.

What should I write in order so that this function only happens once for the initial install?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with phonegap, but the general logic should be the same.

Enclose the code in an if statement that checks if a certain flag value exists in a persistent storage like SharedPreferences. If the value has been set, then the code has been run. If it's not set, then it hasn't been run. If it hasn't been run, run your code and then set the value in the persistent storage so that it isn't run again.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you can set a flag and check for this flag each time you launch the app.

The PhoneGap equivalent of ShardPreferences is LocalStorage. The variable you set in LocalStorage will stay saved even if the app is closed.

Information about this LocalStorage can be found here:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_localstorage_localstorage.md.html

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of using `LocalStorage`?

Comment: An example is given in the link i provided in my answer. 
in short:
-to write something to local storage:
`window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");`
-to retrieve the value you stored earlier:
`var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key")`

Comment: localStorage gets cleared by the system when it likes to do so, do not use it.